# How to remove strings of similar type with multiple occurrence using R?

Tags: r

I am new to R programming and I am performing Text mining. How to remove similar type of strings (eg. "android", "androidaaadeshnimbolafalsefalsenana", "androidaaamirhatruefalsenana"  etc with  multiple occurrence in a document so to get clean document for further processing. I have already tried gsub and the variation in the word is huge which will take a lot of time if it is done manually for all the variations. 
Please help..!

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expressions in gsub to take any work starting with android

```
txt <- 'I am new to R programming and I am performing Text mining. How to remove similar type of strings (eg. "android", "androidaaadeshnimbolafalsefalsenana", "androidaaamirhatruefalsenana" etc with multiple occurrence in a document so to get clean document for further processing. I have already tried gsub and the variation in the word is huge which will take a lot of time if it is done manually for all the variations. Please help.'

gsub("\\bandroid\\w*\\b", "", txt)
```

> [1] "I am new to R programming and I am performing Text mining. How to remove similar type of strings (eg. \"\", \"\", \"\" etc with multiple occurrence in a document so to get clean document for further processing. I have already tried gsub and the variation in the word is huge which will take a lot of time if it is done manually for all the variations. Please help."

The `\b` marks the start and end of the word, the `\w*` looks for zero or more word characters.